# Rails: Need help with nested form rejecting nested object but still creating main object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, nested-forms

I have the following in my user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :gym_users

  attr_accessible :gym_users_attributes, :gym_users
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :gym_users, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:role_id].blank? }

end
```

This correctly rejects the `gym_user` model if the `role_id` is not present, the problem is it still creates the user and simply doesn'
t create the `gym_user`.  Is there a way to make it not create or delete the user when the `gym_user` is rejected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add

```
validates_associated :gym_users
```

to your `User` model and move validation from `reject_if` to `GymUsers` model

```
validates_presence_of :role_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `validates :gym_users, :presence => true` to your User model